# Monte Carlo and random walk

Tags: monte-carlo, random-walk

Can a [Monte Carlo-Simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) be considered as a kind of ensembles of [random walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)?

Comment: Maybe not Monte Carlo simulation alone as but maybe Markov Chain monte carlo? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo

Comment: I'm not aware of the difference between MC and MCMC so why isn't MC already something like a random walk?

Comment: Because there's no notion of walking—your next sample is utterly independent of your previous one. In a random walk, your position at the current time step is going to be one step from your previous position.